# Wordpress change post date format from english to japanese

Tags: php, wordpress, date, date-format

For my WordPress V-4.9.1 I want to change the **Post date** format from **English to Japanese** like `DECEMBER 29, 2017 to 2017年12月29日`. I know it is possible if I change the WordPress admin language but without changing the language is it possible?

Please let me know if anyone knows about a solution or any other plugin that could help. Is it possible?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible , No need to plugin for this simple task, You can store month and year in array in the japanes language and where you want to show fetch and compare it..

Comment: Where to do you want to effect this change? Front end or back end? If on the front/user end - then work with your theme to achieve this by utilizing `the_date()` https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time and https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date